# JDBC single row resultset access error

Tags: sql, jdbc, resultset

I have a single row query output loks like below

```
Product | Process | s_int
--------------------------
W01     | AP_03   | 1
```

To access the data I am using result set (rSet)

```
rSet.first(); 
do{
     product = rSet.getString("PRODUCT");
     process = rSet.getString("PROCESS");
     s_int = rSet.getInt("S_INT");

     System.out.println("Hello Product["+rSet.getString("PRODUCT")+"] Process["+rSet.getString("PROCESS")+"] S_Int["+rSet.getInt("sint")+"]");
}while(rSet.next());
```

I am getting this error:

> The result set has no current row
>   and the returns are null and 0.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you need to check the result of your `first()` call (with an `if`), see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first() The easy way is to replace the do / while by a while here

Comment: you need to call `next()` **before** you access the data. Your code calls it _after_ that

Answer (score 1):

[`ResultSet.first()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#first--) returns a `boolean` indicating if it is on a row or not:

> `true` if the cursor is on a valid row; `false` if there are no rows in the result set

Check this before attempting to access the `ResultSet`. An alternate structure to code:

```
//final ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery("...");
while (rSet.next())
{
}
```

Comment: I have tried     while (rSet.next())
{
} I am getting the same error. but rSet is not empty as a counter inside the while getting to 1

Comment: @Dhiman You need to **do** things in the while loop, otherwise when the while loop exits, you are **after** the last row. You only need to replace your do-while-loop with a while-loop and remove the unnecessary call to `first()`.